# Testcafe and Shadow Dom

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a webpage that uses web component. I am able to select all the elements and perform assertions like checking the `exists`, `innerText`. however when it comes to performing `click`, it does not work. I would like to know if there is any restriction with performing clicks on element that is in `shadow-root`?

Sample

i have a parent div with id `#pricePlans` which i then use as a base to select the elements inside it. You can see an example of how i did the Selector below. The cursor does not even hover to the button for me.

`this.marathiCard = Selector(() => document.querySelector('#pricePlans').shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('[class*="grid-item"]')).nth(1);
this.marathiSignUpButton = this.marathiCard.find('[class*="c-btn c-btn--primary"]'); 
await t.click (this.marathiSignUpButton);`
thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

How about using `.shadowRoot`, you could write something like this:

```js
test('Click inside shadowDOM', async t => {
    const shadowBtn = Selector(() => document.querySelector('#abc').shadowRoot.querySelector('#btn1'));

    await t        
        .click(shadowBtn);
});
```

There're some examples on Github, e.g. https://gist.github.com/AlexanderMoskovkin/897073929442db031d518e1e6db4ec9e or https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2172

Comment: thank you for your response. Ive used .shadowRoot to select my element as well. i am pretty sure that the selector works right because i could perform assertion on the `innerText` but when it comes to clicking it does not seem to work. Ive put an example of how my Selectors look above.

Comment: Can you perhaps give us an example of the DOM and ideally the page where you're trying to achieve this? I don't know why it doesn't work but perhaps when more people have a chance to play around with it, someone would come and give you the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Please download the page here https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiCRZHD12JeaZ_xe_1vGYevBKgM?e=ZeULCG 

if you scroll down you will find 'Our Subscriptions' section and that is a web component in shadowroot. I am try to perform a click on any of the 'Start 14 days for free' buttons. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One more way to achieve it is with [shadowRoot()](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402745/reference/test-api/selector/shadowroot) selector:

```js
test('Click inside shadowDOM', async t => {
    const shadowBtn = Selector('#abc').shadowRoot().child('#btn1');

    await t.click(shadowBtn);
});
```